# How can I get the Huawei E160 modem to work on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, huawei

I've got problem with e160 on ubuntu 12.04. I can't configure network manager and connect because NM can't see the e160. I've tried lot of solutions with no result.

```
ateusz@mateusz-Aspire-5738:~$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1003 -H 
[sudo] password for mateusz: 

aLooking for default devices ... 
   found matching product ID 
   adding device 
 Found device in default mode, class or configuration (1) 
Accessing device 002 on bus 001 ... 
Getting the current device configuration ... 
OK, got current device configuration (1) 
Using first interface: 0x00 
Using endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x82 (in) 
Not a storage device, skipping SCSI inquiry 

USB description data (for identification) 
------------------------- 
Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology 
     Product: HUAWEI Mobile 
  Serial No.: not provided 
------------------------- 
Sending Huawei control message ... 
 OK, Huawei control message sent 
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

`dmesg`:

```
[  521.480062] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd 
[  521.617792] option 1-4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  521.617945] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
[  521.618062] option 1-4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  521.618232] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1 
[  530.840276] option: option_instat_callback: error -108 
[  530.840455] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1 
[  530.840484] option 1-4:1.0: device disconnected 
[  537.680378] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
[  537.680398] option 1-4:1.1: device disconnected 
[  537.792088] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd 
[  537.929549] option 1-4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  537.929702] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
[  537.929818] option 1-4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  537.929993] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1 
[  547.224294] option: option_instat_callback: error -108 
[  547.224470] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1 
[  547.224511] option 1-4:1.0: device disconnected 
[  556.988066] tty_ldisc_hangup: waiting (usb-storage) for ttyUSB0 took too long, but we keep waiting... 
[  558.990663] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 
[  558.990698] option 1-4:1.1: device disconnected 
[  559.100068] usb 1-4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd 
[  559.241293] option 1-4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  559.241446] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0 
[  559.241565] option 1-4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected 
[  559.241739] usb 1-4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1 
[  568.728283] option: option_instat_callback: error -108 
[  568.728466] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1 
[  568.728496] option 1-4:1.0: device disconnected
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 064e:a103 Suyin Corp. Acer/HP Integrated Webcam [CN0314] 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 09da:c20a A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
```

Comment: Can you tell use *specifically* what you have tried?

Comment: http://blog.pew.cc/blog/Getting+the+Huawei+E160+to+work+/ mainly all soutions with usb_modeswitch, but when i try run it, returns help of usb_modeswitch

Comment: I'm also getting this problem with a huawei e160. Eliminated power problems so far. Going to try a different hub next. Did you ever resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I got the Huawei e160 working out of the box under Ubuntu 12.04.
from a clean install with all the updates.

Just make sure there is no pin code on the simcard!

Put your simcard in any mobile phone first, on it and check if you need to put a pin code. If thats the case, do it, and then via the mobile phone settings get rid of that pin code.
Now it should work out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Fwiw, I've tried a different USB hub and the 108 and 71 errors went away.

Googling Linux USB 108 71 gets you hits mentioning power related problems.

I got less problems with a good PSU for the hub and then no problems with same PSU and different hub.